# WSP Builder deployment problems

Tags: wspbuilder

I have been creating features using WSP builder but I realized it acts really random, sometimes when we build/deploy solutions they are either not updated few times or sometimes they simply don't want to get loaded When I attach it to "OWSTimer"

I am just wondering if its just me or happens to everyone, as I find it easier to develop a feature using a template and then deploy it as in that case it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem was with my timer job code so changing logic and increasing duration it was running solved the problem.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try right click project, hover over wspBuilder and select "Recycle AppPools" . Do the same again but this time for "Recycle Services Timer".

Goto sharepoint site, site action, site settings, goto feature and disable.

Try right click project, hover over wspBuilder and select Uninstall.

Now goto the folder where the wsp is created and delete it, go back to the project and build, then build using WSP and then deploy using WSP

hope it helps!

Comment: +1 but tried that already, but nothing changed

Comment: made some ammendments to the post

Comment: tried that as well, but no gain, its giving errors on run time for a specific dll, which I recently added to gac

Comment: whats the error its giving you?

Comment: it couldn't find the method I added in that specific project's dll